# Java inheritance... I think. Maybe not

Tags: java, inheritance

I need to make a collection of several different classes. In my mind, the sub classes inherit from a more general super class. So I have the class SuperClass, which currently has a member variable o of Object type, which will take a single instance of one of the subclasses class SubClassA and class SubClassB. SubClassA and SubClassB have some things in common, such as the need to create database tables to hold descriptions of themselves. Therefore, each subclass needs to have a method CreateDatabaseTables(). Currently I have a collection of SuperClass instances, each of them containing an Object o which can be one of several classes that I will not know at compile time. Maybe this isn't the best way to do this...

My question is, when I iterate over the collection, will I be able to call something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < superClassArray.size; i++)
{
  superClassInstance[i].o.CreateDatabaseTables();
}
```

without having to cast Object o into one of the SubClasses?

Or have I gooned up the whole thing and I am just plain doing it wrong? Is this concept called inheritance, or is it something else? I don't think it is inheritance because I do not intend to write a CreateDatabaseTables() method in the SuperClass. Each class will have to have its own method.

Comment: A super class should have ***no*** dependencies on its subclasses. Your design is broken and should be fixed. I suspect that you're relying too much on inheritance for problems that don't require inheritance to solve, but rather should be solved with composition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using inheritance, but composition.

You don't need members in your base class:

```
abstract class SuperClass
{
    public abstract void CreateDatabaseTables();
}

class SubClassA extends SuperClass
{
    public void CreateDatabaseTables() { /*do whatever*/ }
}
class SubClassB extends SuperClass
{
    public void CreateDatabaseTables() { /*do whatever else*/ }
}
```

And simply call the overriden method on the base class:

```
// Collection<SuperClass> superClassInstance;
// you can populate superClassInstance with objects of type
// SubClassA or SubClassB
for (int i = 0; i < superClassInstance.length; i++)
{
    superClassInstance[i].CreateDatabaseTables();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, @Luchian. I can already tell that this will be much better.

Comment: @Luchian - I attempted to edit this post to correct a couple of Java syntax errors, but I was rejected (go figure).  1.  If there's an abstract method in a class, the entire class needs to be marked as abstract.  2.  In the for loop, you have "i < superClassArray.size".  That should be updated to "i < superClassInstance.length" to be consistent/correct with the rest of that code block.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, how do I add subclass members to the collection? I have ArrayList<SuperClass> superClassList; and it seems that I cannot use superClassList.add(new SubClassA()); since the ArrayList is looking for SuperClass objects.

Comment: @MrGibbage That's the thing, `SubClassA()` **is a** `SuperClass`. It should work. Are you sure you're deriving from `SuperClass` using `extends`?

Comment: Whoops. I had extended SubClassA and SubClassB, but started testing with "SubClassC", which I had not extended. I should have known. This is working perfectly now!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - I tried to edit again to fix the erroneous reference to "superClassInstance.length" as I noticed that you mentioned in comments that superClassInstance is a Collection.  I tried to update the post to be "superClassInstance.size()" instead but was rejected again.  Seems that editing code is frowned upon round here...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `CreateDatabaseTables` as an abstract method in the `SuperClass` and define `o` to be not an `Object`, but a `SuperClass`.

But, I have a feel that you are doing something wrong with that `o` member variable - it's not a common situation when a superclass needs to have a subclass as a member.

Comment: why does `CreateDatabaseTables` have to be defined as abstract?

Comment: Because `SuperClass` itself doesn't have an implementation of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use an interface instead of inheritance

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Don't you means `as well as inheritance`  Interfaces without inheritance are not very useful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an interface which has the method `createDatabaseTables()` which you use instead of Object. Even better is to make your object have this method and not access the field directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are never instantiating the superclass, then make it abstract,

```
public abstract class MySuperClass {
    public abstract void createDatabaseTables();
}

public class Child extends MySuperClass {
       public abstract void createDatabaseTables(){
              //bleh
       }
}
```

Then all the implementers will implement it themselves and you will have access to it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning...

> My question is, when I iterate over the collection, will I be able to
>   call something like
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < superClassArray.size; i++) {  
>    superClassInstance[i].o.CreateDatabaseTables(); 
> }
> ```
>
> without having to cast Object o into one of the SubClasses?

you will have to put a cast on that Object in order for the SubClass to be recognized.